# how to remove single quote from the value of hidden field in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am reading hidden field value using javascript. The value I am getting is within single quote( '78963' ). I can i remove this single quote ? I want the value without single quote(  78963  ). Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Do you mean simply this: `yourValue.replace(/'/g, "");`? Or am I missing something? What are the possible values of the string?

Answer (score 5):

I guess you simply want to convert your string value to numeric.

Just use `parseInt()`:

```
parseInt("78963", 10);  // 78963
```

If the value pretends to be floating, there is `parseFloat()` method:

```
parseFloat("78963.1");  // 78963.1
```

And one more shortcut to make casting:

```
+"78963";  // 78963
```

---

In case if you simply want to replace single quotes, you may use:

```
"'78963'".replace(/'/g, "");  // "78963"
```

(as stated by others) or do tricky split:

```
"'78963'".split("'")[1];  // "78963"
```

Comment: This doesn't seem correct given something like `<input type="hidden" value="'123'"/>`, which is how I interpret the question.

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg Well, it can be. Updated my answer.

Comment: Great. Your original interpretation may well have been correct. The question is a bit vague.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .replace() function on strings: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
str.substr(1, str.length - 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `$('#element').val()`, you will get exact value. here element will be the id of hidden box.

Answer (score 0):

If it's true that the value of the hidden input field contains single quotes, the (in my opinion) best answer is the one which JamesAllardice put in a comment:

```
yourValue.replace(/'/g, "");
```